# generic way for communication between shopping cart and applet

Tags: web-applications, architecture, applet, shopping-cart

I am building a configurable "applet" (not Flash, but HTML and Javascript). The planned functions are similar to a car configurator, where you select color, engine power or seat covers. The actual product will be listed by various online shops as a single product. The configuration should be done within the page that presents the product.

The shops in question all use different CMSes. The problem is, that I'd have to write code for each shopping system to integrate the applet into the shop. Is there an industry standard for doing this? Or if that is not the case: Where is the point of minimal necessary communication of the shop with the configurator, where I'd best place the interface?

My current idea is to to configure the shop on page load by a JSON object, telling it about its environment and about the last state of the product (someone might want to alter an ordered product). Once the user has finished configuring, an AJAX call is used to send the configuration to the server. There the product is added to the shopping cart and a redirect to another page (product overview etc.) is requested.

Is this a good way to do that? What would be better?

Comment: I wouldn't use the word "applet" here. Applets are java.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan  Though the term 'applet' has become associated with Java, it actually means 'small application', which might be quite appropriate here.

Comment: I guess even if you considered applets solely being Java, the answer to this question would likely be the same.